# Java Jackson serializer grab variable name

Tags: java, json, serialization, reflection, jackson

I have a class structure like so:

```
public class Foo {
    private Foo2 title;
    private Foo2 message;
}

public class Foo2 {
    private String value;
    private String variable;
}
```

When I serialize these classes into json I want to output the following json:

```
{
    "type": "title",
    "value": "...",
    "variable": "..."
},
{
    "type": "message",
    "value": "...",
    "variable": "..."
}
```

I made a custom serializer class like so:

```
public class FooSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Foo> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Foo value,
                          JsonGenerator gen,
                          SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeStringField("type", /* get variable name */);
        gen.writeStringField("value", value.getValue());
        gen.writeStringField("variable", value.getVariable());
        gen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

But I'm not sure how to get the variable name. Am I going about this the right way? If so, how do I get the variable name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented a possible solution that I think may achieve what you are looking for or at least point you towards your own.

```
public class FooSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Foo> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Foo value,
                          JsonGenerator gen,
                          SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {

        gen.writeStartObject();

        Field[] fields = value.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

        for (Field field : fields) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            try {
                Foo2 obj = (Foo2) field.get(value);
                gen.writeFieldName(field.getName());
                gen.writeStartObject();
                gen.writeStringField("type", field.getName());
                gen.writeStringField("value", obj.getValue());
                gen.writeStringField("variable", obj.getVariable());
                gen.writeEndObject();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        gen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

Test case:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        Foo2 message = new Foo2("valueMessage", "variableMessage");
        Foo2 title = new Foo2("valueTitle", "variableTitle");
        Foo foo = new Foo(title, message);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addSerializer(Foo.class, new FooSerializer());
        mapper.registerModule(module);

        String serialized = mapper.writeValueAsString(foo);
        System.out.println(serialized);

}
```

Output JSON:

```
  {
    "message": {
        "type": "message",
        "value": "valueMessage",
        "variable": "variableMessage"
    },
    "title": {
        "type": "title",
        "value": "valueTitle",
        "variable": "variableTitle"
    }
}
```

I could not find a way to write a nested object without giving the node a name, maybe you can find a way. In any case let me know if any help is needed tweaking this to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you're looking fo this:

```
// GET variables of Foo
Field[] fields= value.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

for(Field f : fields){
    String fieldName = f.getName());
}
```

Using the getName method, you will have your variables name.

I hope I have helped you!